# How to retrieve wav file from API?

Tags: python, xml, api, audio, wav

I am working on Python3.4.4
I tried to use a Merriam-Webster API, and here is an example link:
http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/collegiate/xml/purple?key=bf534d02-bf4e-49bc-b43f-37f68a0bf4fd

There is a  file under the  tag, you will see after you open the url.

And I am wondering that how can I retrieve that wav file......

Because it is kind of just a string to me......

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just sort it out.
Usually you need to look at the instructions for the API, I look it up on the official website and it tells you that how you are going to retrieve that. In this case you are going to another url, and then wala